# Resolving a promise in a JavaScript Proxy object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a JavaScript Proxy that allows me to deeply traverse an object's properties but when I run a method, I want it to return a promise with a new proxy that will let me deeply traverse that object.

Example:

```
const foo = createProxy()
const result = await foo.any.number.of.properties.deep()
const result2 = await result.foo.bar()
const result3 = await result2.off.we.go.again()
```

I have tried creating a proxy of a function and this works when I want to return a proxy synchronously from a method call, however when I try to return a promise it loops infinitely.

However when I capture a `then` property and try to run the callback to pass the proxy to it, I break the browser with an infinite loop.

```
const createProxy = <T>(path) => {
  return new Proxy(function () {}, {
    apply(_target, _thisArg, _args) {
      console.log("exec", path);
      return createProxy([]);
    },
    get(_target, key) {
      if (key === "then") {
        return (cb) => {
          cb(createProxy([...path, key]));
        };
      }
      return createProxy([...path, key]);
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to `await` anything here? It's all synchronous. Or do you want to add asynchronous behaviour later?

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? What should "deeply traverse an object's properties" entail? Which object? What do you want to happen when you use the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The object that you fulfill a promise with must not be another thenable - otherwise the `resolve()` algorithm will try to wait for that nested promise.

The easiest choice in your case would be to return a promise that is fulfilled with a proxy, not a proxy for a promise, from method calls, and to make your proxies non-thenable:

```
function createProxy<T>(path = []) {
  return new Proxy(function () {
    console.log("exec", path);
    return Promise.resolve(createProxy([]));
  }, {
    get(_target, key) {
      if (typeof key === 'string' && key !== "then")
        return createProxy([...path, key]);
      else
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    },
  });
}
```

Btw, notice that for `await` to work, you don't even need to return a promise from the method calls - a normal value would work as well. Just make sure that either it's not thenable, or its `then` method works as required.